# How to map string array const to union type

Tags: typescript

I have a string array from which I want to define a new type where the properties are actually elements in the array. There are different kinds of arrays and I have a function that returns different types based on the input array.

```js
const RGBColor = ["R" , "G" ,  "B"] as const
const YRBColor = ["Y" , "R" ,  "B"] as const

function Map<TInputColor extends readonly string[]>(x: TInputColor): TOutputColor<TInputColor>;
```

If input is RGBColor, the output type would be

```js
{
   R: number;
   G: number;
   B: number;
}
```

If input is YRBColor, the output type would be

```js
{
   Y: number;
   R: number;
   B: number;
}
```

So, how should I define TOutputColor?

```js
TOutputColor<TInputColor>
{
   ???????
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mapped types:

```
type TOutputColor<TInputColor extends readonly string[]> = {
  [K in TInputColor[number]]: number;
};
```